# After running ./byfn.sh up got this Error. ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm trying to install Hyperledger in my Ubuntu Stand Alone system, After running **sudo ./byfn.sh up** i got this Error please help..!

> Error: failed to create deliver client for orderer: orderer client
> failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new
> connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing:
> dial tcp: lookup orderer.example.com: no such host" !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
> Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
> ========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========
>
> ERROR !!!! Test failed

Answer (score 0):

byfn.sh script was used with older fabric versions and is no longer supported. The latest [fabric-samples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples) is having a network.sh script to setup fabric network. Detailed tutorial is available in [official docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html).